# How to access global variables from separate processes

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i have two python processes running on different cores that need to communicate between each other while they are running. At the moment i can achieve this via multithreading;

```py
import threading
x=0
def a():
    global x
    if x==100:
        pass
        #Do something

def b():
    global x
    while 1:
        x=x+1
t1=threading.thread(target=a)
t2=threading.thread(target=b)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

But i would like to use the `multiprocessing` module instead. Is there any way to covert the above code into something using multiprocessing?

Comment: Processes do not share memory, so it's significantly harder than sharing values between threads.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module offers two ways to do it: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: @blhsing, that example only seems to use a single process...

Comment: Take a look at [sharing global variables in python using multiprocessing](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/02/19/sharing-global-variables-in-python-using-multiprocessing/)

Comment: looks interesting @nathancy, i'll take a look

Comment: @3NiGMa By either sharing memory or updating objects in the parent process, multiple processes can effectively update and read the same objects. You can simply add another process in to the examples in the documentation to make it work in the way you desire.

Comment: could you add this as a complete answer using the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example like your original but using multiprocessing...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def a(x):
    while True:
        if x.value == 10:
            print('Done.  x = ', x.value) 
            break

def b(x):
    for _ in range(10):
        x.value += 1

x = Value('i', 0)   # integer with initial value of 0
t1=Process(target=a, args=(x,))
t2=Process(target=b, args=(x,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Note that while I did pass in `x` as a parameter to the function, it looks like this still works if you simply use it as global, as you have above.  The real trick here is to use the `multiprocessing.Value` object and access it with `x.value`.